# How to do something for each value in Datetime Range C#

Tags: c#, datetime, range

I've got the following Code

```
  public static IEnumerable<DateRange> GetWeekdayRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DayOfWeek weekEndsOn = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        var currStartDate = startDate;
        var currDate = startDate;
        while (currDate < endDate)
        {
            while (currDate.DayOfWeek != weekEndsOn && currDate < endDate)
            {
                currDate = currDate.AddDays(1);
            }
            yield return new DateRange { WeekStartDate = currStartDate, WeekEndDate = currDate };
            currStartDate = currDate.AddDays(1);
            currDate = currStartDate;
        }
    }

    public struct DateRange
    {
        public DateTime WeekStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime WeekEndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I add the values to fields in a word doc. Now I want to create a document for each WeekRange

```
var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var template = word.Documents.Open($@"C:\Path\Template.docx");
var range = GetWeekdayRange(start, end);
        foreach (var val in range)
        {
            template.Variables["WocheVon"].Value = @$"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}";
            template.Variables["WocheBis"].Value = @$"{1:yyyy-MM-dd}";
            template.Variables["VollerName"].Value = fullName;
            template.Fields.Update();
            template.SaveAs(@$"C:\Path\{fullName}_{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.docx");

        }
        template.Close();
        word.Quit();
```

start and end are datetimes from a datetimepicker.
This only creates a single doc, I need one for each WeekDayRange between start and end.

Maybe someone has an idea of what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be missing this:

```
template.Variables["WocheVon"].Value = @$"{val.WeekStartDate:yyyy-MM-dd}";
template.Variables["WocheBis"].Value = @$"{val.WeekEndDate:yyyy-MM-dd}";
```

And this:

```
template.SaveAs(@$"C:\Path\{fullName}_{val.WeekStartDate:yyyy-MM-dd}_{val.WeekEndDate:yyyy-MM-dd}.docx");
```

You're putting placeholders in the `@$` and not the actual dates.